# IDL CALL_EXTERNAL pass array

Tags: linker, fortran, idl

I am currently trying to interface some fortran routines with IDL, yes it is as painful as it sounds. To start with I tried to get the example given in the IDL documentation to work, but here i run in to a very strange problem. When I try to pass an array, as demonstrated here http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/FORTRANExamples.html, the code only passes the first element.

Here is the code i use. Currently I use the c wrapper given in the above link.

The fortran code. (clf.F)

```
  SUBROUTINE SUM_ARRAY1(array, n, sum)
  implicit none
  INTEGER n,i
  INTEGER array(3), sum
  sum=0.0

  DO i=1,n
     st = sum + array(i)
     sum = st
  ENDDO
  !sum = n
  !sum = array(1)
  RETURN
  END
```

And here is the c code. (caller.c)

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  void sum_array(int argc, void *argv[])
  {
  extern void sum_array1_();/* Fortran routine */
  int *n;
  int *s, *f;
  f = (int *) argv[0];/* Array pntr */
  n = (int *) argv[1];/* Get # of elements */
  s = (int *) argv[2];/* Pass back result a parameter */
  sum_array1_(f, n, s);/* Compute sum */
  }
```

I compile and link with

```
 gfortran -c clf.F -fPIC 
 && gcc -c caller.c -fPIC 
 && gcc -shared -fpic clf.o caller.o -o mylb.so
```

And call in IDL with

```
a = [5,6,7]                                            
sm = 0                                                     
S = CALL_EXTERNAL('mylb.so','sum_array', a, N_ELEMENTS(a), sm)
print, sm,a
```

Now this should return the sum of my numbers, in other words sm = 18. However, when I run the code as given by exelisvis I get some random number. Now I have played around with it. As you can see I have tried to set sum = n and sum = array(1). Here I get the correct output, 3 and 5. However if I try with sum = array(2) I get back to strange numbers.

From what I can gather by doing some debugging is that the whole array is not passed to the fortran array. I have also tried with a fortran interface and with different compilers. When I used the fortran wrapper I tried to define an array here and past it to the subroutine, that worked like a charm.

So it seems to me that the problem is relay in the passing of information from IDL to fortran/c. It surprises me that I can not even get the examples on the webpage to work. I am currently on a 64 system and tomorrow I will try to compile in 32 and see if that changes anything, the manual mentions this. However, I need to get it working for a 64bit system.

Since this is very new territory to me I hope that there is some silly mistake here somewhere and that someone can spot it. All forms of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran-iso-c-binding/info ?

Comment: I have not looked at that one specifically no.

Anyway I figured it out, turns out it has to do with the fact that an IDL_INT is equal to an short and an integer*2 in fortran.  I was sure I cheeked this, but I guess I did not.

So if anyone happens upon this in the future, make sure your data types are 100% correct. 

Sorry for the unnecessary question.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your array initialization statement in IDL to:

```
a = long([5,6,7])
```

Also cast `sm` and `N_ELEMENTS` as `long()` in your IDL.

Comment: Hi Bill, welcome to Stack Overflow :) Could you give a brief sentence or two explaining why these changes are needed? This will make your answer more useful to other readers :)